# Why does my MySQL search take so long?

Tags: mysql, database, apache

I have a MySQL table with about 150 million rows. When i perform a search with one clause it takes about 1.5 minutes for it to get the result. Why does it take so long? I am running debian in virtualbox with 2 CPU cores and 4gb of ram. I am using MySQL and apache2.

I am a bit new to this so so don't know what more information to provide.

Comment: There is no index on the column.

Comment: You ought to EXPLAIN PLAN on that query.  If you see TABLE SCAN in the result, you can fix it by adding appropriate indexes on the columns that appear in your WHERE clause.

Comment: Provide the statement and the result of the explain

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It helps to give us some specific information about your problem.

Comment: In part because there are 150 million rows. Please provide the EXPLAIN for your query as well as CREATE TABLE statements for ALL relevant tables.

Comment: Adding an index on the column fixed the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searches, or rather **queries**, in databases like MySQL or any other Relational Database Management System (RDBMS) are subject to a number of factors for performance including:

1. Structure of the WHERE clause and Indexing to support it
2. Contention for system resources such as Memory and CPU
3. The amount of data being retrieved and how it is delivered

Some quick wins and strategies for each:

**Structure of the WHERE clause and Indexing to support it**

Order your WHERE clause in the order that will cut down the results by the biggest margin as you go from left to right.  Also, use [Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimization-indexes.html) and align these Indexes to the order of those columns in the WHERE clause.  If you're searching a large database with `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SomeID = 5 AND CreatedDate > '10-01-2015'` then be sure you have an Index in place with the columns `SomeID` and `CreatedDate` in the order that makes the most sense.  If SomeID is a column that is highly unique or likely to have results much smaller than `CreatedDate > '10-01-2015'` then you should create the query in that order and an Index with columns in the same order.

**Contention for system resources such as Memory and CPU**

Are you using a table that is constantly updated?  There are transactional databases ([OLTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_transaction_processing)) and databases meant for analysis ([OLAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_analytical_processing)).  If you're hitting a table that is being constantly updated you may be slowing things down for everyone including yourself.  Remember you're a citizen in an environment and as such you need to respect the other use cases.  This includes knowing a bit about how the system is used, what resources are available and making sure you are mindful of how your queries will affect others.

**The amount of data being retrieved and how it is delivered**

Even the best query cannot escape the time it takes to get data from one place to another.  You can optimize settings of the RDBMS, have incredible bandwidth etc. but many factors including disk IOPS, network bandwidth, et. al. all play into a cost of doing business.  Make sure you're using the right protocols to transfer, have good disk IOPS and all the Best Practices around MySQL.

Some final thoughts:

- If you're using AWS and hosting your database in the cloud you may
  consider using [Amazon Aurora](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/highly-scalable-mysql-compat-rds-db-engine/) which is a MySQL-compatible RDBMS
  that is substantially faster than MySQL.

Comment: Thank you very much  for the reply! This was the first time I heard about indexes except for primary keys and didn't know they speeded up the search. Feeling really dumb now for not doing more research before posting the question.

Adding an index to the column made the search take 0.3 seconds instead of 1.5.

Comment: I am in the top 3% on here though I quit contributing years ago because people are a little militant about answering genuine questions for first timers.  Hope this helps your growth.